# Browser/addon which shows what's been downloaded so far regardless of formatting and layout?

Tags: windows-xp, browser, browser-addons, download, performance

Every now and then a website becomes super-slow (but not broken) because there are too many people looking at it at the same time. When I try and view such a site, say with Firefox, I can see that it is downloading all sorts of components of the site because of the progress information printed at the bottom of the window and I'm sitting there thinking "If only the browser would show me what it's got so far. I don't care if its a jumbled mess, I just want to see what you've got". Does any browser offer such an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `Net` tab on the [Firebug addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/). It's awesome!

[image]

Comment: er, I believe OP wants to see the *actual content* rather than what component has been downloaded

Comment: @sathya: yes I did want to see the content, but it seems you can get that through firebug despite the fact that th3dude19's selected image does not show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Net" tab with the FireBug extension for Firefox.

You can even extend the Firebug extension with Yahoo!'s YSlow addon for Firebug.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Comment: Is that not what I suggested?

Comment: Google or Yahoo! extension? What?

Comment: sorry th3dude, i had my response typed already but i couldn't post it right away cause of superuser's 3 min between posts rule.